# Mocha test isn't running properly in loops

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, mocha.js, chai

I have a JSON with every key containing an array of strings, I added two loops

1. One to get all keys
2. Second to get array against keys

I'm using my second loop to test each value in array. But what is happening is it never goes to the `it` block and also throwing error on `before`

```
Cannot read value of the function(waitForReadiness) from null (resultPage)
```

The code is here:

```
//SearchData is the JSON 

for (const key of allKeys) {
            const valuesArray: string[] = (SearchData as any)[key];

            for (const value of valuesArray) {
                let someURL = new UrlHandler().SearchResultUrl(destination, 30, 35);
                let resultPage: ResultPageMarketing = new ResultPageMarketing();

                before(async() => {
                   someURL = someURL.concat(`?${key}=${value}`);
                   resultPage = await BrowserHelper.open(someURL) as ResultPageMarketing;
                   await resultPage.waitForReadiness();
                   await resultPage.waitForResultsListContainer();
                })

                it('should have appended filter option applied and selected HRP')
                    .test(async () => {
                        const url: boolean = (await BrowserHelper.getCurrentUrl()).includes(`param=${key}=${value}`);
                        assert.isTrue(url, `Property Filter '${key}=${value}' wasn't appended to URL`);
                    });

                it('should filter results according to the selected option')
                    .test(async () => {
                        const hasResults: boolean = await resultPage.hasResults();
                        assert.isTrue(hasResults, `Page doesn't have any results against property filter '${key}=${value}'`);
                    });
            }
        }
```

The values are appending correctly in the browser but the page doesn't wait to load and append next value and so not running test.

**I'm using protractor, chai, and mocha**

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
let flow = protractor.promise.controllFlow();
flow.execute(function(){
    for(){
     //your codeenter code here
    }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.